# How can i access to a Gnome application JavaScript function from a HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, gtk, gnome-3

I learned that [how to embedded a HTML page to a gnome](http://developer.gnome.org/gnome-devel-demos/unstable/hellognome.js.html.en) JavaScript application and show it in a Gtk+ frame.

```
// Create a webview to show the web app
this._webView = new Webkit.WebView ();

// Put the web app into the webview
this._webView.load_uri (GLib.filename_to_uri (GLib.get_current_dir() +
    "/hellognome.html", null));

// Put the webview into the window
this._window.add (this._webView);

// Show the window and all child widgets
this._window.show_all();
```

Now i am going to access a Gtk+ API (like accessing to file system ) or a JavaScript function in my gnome JavaScript application from this HTML (hellognome.html) file using JavaScript?

Somthing like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello, GNOME!</title>

        <!-- Use JavaScript to show a greeting when someone clicks the button -->
        <script type="application/javascript">
        function greeting () {
            document.getElementById ("greeting").innerHTML = ("O hai!");

            //// access to a Gtk+ API (like accessing to file system ) 
                 or a JavaScript function in my gnome JavaScript application.

        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <br /> <br />
        <button type="button" onclick="greeting()">Hello, GNOME!</button>

        <!-- Empty H1 element gets filled in when the button is clicked -->
        <h1 id="greeting"></h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use GTK APIs from inside the JS inside the HTML. You'll have to set up some method of communication between the two. For example, connect to the [`window-object-cleared`](http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk/stable/webkitgtk-webkitwebview.html#WebKitWebView-window-object-cleared) signal and set some methods on the window object.

Comment: Could you bring an example?

Comment: Not in Javascript, but here is an example in C: https://github.com/ptomato/gnome-inform7/blob/master/src/panel.c In `i7_panel_init`, at line 533, I create a JS class with the methods I want to call from the JS code inside the HTML. Then in the handler for `window-object-cleared` at line 846 I set that class as a property of the window object. The implementations of the methods are the `js_` functions at the beginning of the file, at line 50 and following.

Comment: @ptomato, do you know if anything like that is possible using the Python Gtk bindings? When I try to implement `window-object-cleared`, it actually crashes the interpreter...

Comment: PyGTK or gi.repository? Where is your code? What error does the interpreter exit with?

Comment: @JackO'Connor I see you filed a bug. For future reference, here is a link to the bug: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=694233