# Is there a way to call Python functions from JS, when using WebKitGtk+ in a Python app?

Tags: javascript, python, webkit, gtk

I'm coming from the Windows Forms world, where they have this `ObjectForScripting` property that makes it trivial to expose C# objects to the JavaScript running inside your WebViews. I'm hoping to do something similar in Python, and WebKitGtk+ seems like a natural choice for the WebView. But there doesn't seem to be an easy way to bind a Python object into JS. Is there an easy way that I'm missing, or maybe an alternative to WebKitGtk+ that would work better for doing this? Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I don't think so. You really might want to rethink how you're going about this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i access to a Gnome application JavaScript function from a HTML page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414103/how-can-i-access-to-a-gnome-application-javascript-function-from-a-html-page)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up going with PyQt for this instead, since it has strong support for exposing native objects to JS. Here are some great starting examples:

http://pysnippet.blogspot.com/2010/01/calling-python-from-javascript-in-pyqts.html
http://pysnippet.blogspot.com/2010/01/more-fun-with-qwebkit.html

Answer (score 4):

Here is a workaround: intercept URLs with a custom scheme.

- Handle the [resource-request-starting](http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk/stable/WebKitWebFrame.html#WebKitWebFrame-resource-request-starting) signal and check if the URL starts with `python:`
- If it does, parse the URL somehow (`eval`? dictionary of allowed functions? Up to you) and call the appropriate function.
- Replace the URL requested with `data:text/plain,<result of function call>`.
- In JavaScript, make an Ajax request to `python:my_function()`.

This is very limited but works, in my case, with Haskell bindings.

Comment: Thanks. This could work if I controlled all my JS, but in this case I'm using some existing JS that expects ordinary function calls to work. I ended up going with Qt, so I'll post that as a separate answer.